# How can I pass filters to a dashboard through url

Tags: kibana, dashboard, elasticsearch-dsl

I have been trying to pass filters as part of url without success.
I followed examples in other threads
I would like to add following filters created manually on dashboard as part of url

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "metadata.test.raw": "test_1"
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "metadata.application.metric": "time"
    }
  }
}
```

These filters were obtained by clicking edit as DSL
I tried to pass one filter as below but that results in error

```
&_a=(filters:!(query:(match_phrase:(metadata%2Etest%2Eraw:test_1))))
```